How To Program Radioddity's QB25 Manually (Without Software)
I want to know how to program a Radioddity QB25 by hand. I have tried their instructions
https://www.radioddity.com/pages/radioddity-qa-bank
for programming using the QB25 using the microphone's keypad.
Although I have tried the exact and several variations of the instructions (below). I cannot hit the repeater from my location, and my ht-s can.
I would love more detailed instructions than what's on their web page. (The following is directly pulled off the web page in case the link falls short.)

Save Channels With Offset Without Using A Computer It is difficult to
save an offset to memory when programming the QB25 without a computer.
The following steps will allow you to save a complete channel with
offsets and any signal tones necessary. Delete channel (if necessary)

Menu 45 Switch to VFO Enter RX Frequency (enter zeros if needed to fill all blanks. Example 146.7000) Enter RX Tone (if needed) Save to
empty channel - Menu 44

Enter TX Frequency (enter zeros if needed to fill all blanks. Example
146.1000) Enter TX Tone (if needed) Save to the same channel as RX frequency - Menu 44 (Hold the Right knob in until it returns to the
operating screen) Change to Memory, Select Channel, and check
operation.

It appears that this problem got resolved by deliberately removing squelch by pressing the Midi button, but that appears not to be the case. Therefore, I am leaving this open in case someone runs across a solution.
